# "survey the landscape" idiomatic?

Tags: idioms, clauses

Can I use the phrase "to survey the landscape" when refering not to an actual outdoors scenery but to something more abstract? In this case, I want to express that I was researching something in a body of literature (meaning that I tried to get an overview of a specific subtopic?), as in: "*I surveyed the landscape of books focusing on* "?

I think I saw this a couple of times already, but right now, I cannot find any thrustworthy reference for this. I this really idiomatic?

Comment: Why the downvote? No offense, but I would really like to understand why this question was considered to be poor in order to improve my future questions.

Comment: I see  no reason for a downvote. The question is clear; you tried to find reference; you ask for help. What more may reasonably be expected of you? Despite all this, no reason was given for the downvote. You will find this one of the more disagreeable features of this otherwise excellent site and I suggest taking a philosophical attitude to such human weaknesses. I have remedied the downvote accordingly.

Comment: Some people just call this a literature survey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could. But it will depend on how you phrase it. I would not say:

> I surveyed the landscape of books ...

in normal prose. It might work as a poetic line. In fact, because you are not looking at an actual landscape, you will be using the term 'landscape' as a metaphor. And that reinforces what I said about the above line working as a poetic line as metaphors are the stock-in-trade of poetry.

A much better line would be:

> I surveyed the landscape of my dreams

Or perhaps:

> The landscape of Babel

To describe a chaotic landscape.

If you are engaged in research, then the usual rule-of-thumb is to use sober language stripped of metaphor. So:

> I surveyed the bibliography on 12th century Andalusian poetry focusing on the poetry and song of Qamar al-Baghdadia.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and helpful answer!

Comment: It would have been better and more informative had it started from definition of *landscape*.

Comment: @Anton: I think most people understand what landscape means - even the blind. It doesn't require definition. If you're suggesting that we have to define everything before saying anything then no-one would say anything. I mean, to define definition leads one into an infinite regress ...